# Scroll Indicator based on four html pages without decreasing percentage when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently programming an e-learning website and thus want a scrolling indicator "summing up" the pages already read. I have four html pages, each html page should make up 25% of the scroll bar. So if you've scrolled through all four pages, it should be 100%. I've already tried the code down below and it works for one html page to go up to 25%. Nevertheless, when I scroll back up, the percentage decreases again. I would want it to stay at 25% once the page is fully scrolled down. I'm a beginner at programming and tried everything I could think of + used google... I just can't find anything that works. I'd be very thankful if you guys could help me.

I've thought maybe if & else might work, so I tried something like this, changing variables, numbers and order but nothing worked:

```
if (scrolled = 25) {document.getElementById("myBar- 
fotografie").style.width = 25 + "%"; }
else {document.getElementById("myBar-fotografie").style.width = scrolled 
+ "%";}
```

I've only tried keeping the bar at 25% so far once it's fully scrolled, not adding the percentages of the four html pages. I don't have a clue how to do that though.

```
<html>
<p> Fotografie </p>
<div class="progress-container">
<div class="progress-bar" id="myBar-fotografie"></div>
</div>
//fotografie is the headline for the four html pages which are subpages
</html>


<style>
.progress-container {
width: 100%;
height: 8px;
background: #ccc;
}

.progress-bar {
height: 8px;
background: #4caf50;
width: 0%;
}
</style>


<script>
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || 
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 25;

document.getElementById("myBar-fotografie").style.width = scrolled + "%";
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your working code e.g. here https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, before you prepare a working code
My example of progressbar at 25%

```js
const ProgressBar = function () {
  let position = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrolls = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let ws = window.pageYOffset, wh = window.innerHeight, dh = document.body.clientHeight;
    let scrollPercent = (ws / (dh - wh)) * 25;

    if (scrolls > position) {
      const progressBar = document.querySelector('#progress');
      if (ws > 50) {
        progressBar.setAttribute('style', 'width:' + scrollPercent + '%');
      } else {
        progressBar.removeAttribute('style');
      }
    }

    position = scrolls;
  });
}();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

h1 span {
  color: rgb(60, 177, 6);
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress" class="bar"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>proggres bar test - <span>scroll</span></h1>
    <div class="lipsum">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu commodo orci, sed elementum massa. Nam sit amet
        elementum
        ipsum, eu laoreet metus. Aenean a ex vel erat aliquam imperdiet eu at justo. Nulla in lobortis tellus. Curabitur
        varius laoreet quam non facilisis. Etiam consequat purus elit, vel euismod ligula faucibus fringilla. Etiam
        cursus dui eros, non egestas nibh congue a. Nullam eu justo neque. Cras rutrum arcu elit. Quisque vestibulum
        et mi vel congue. Curabitur a ultrices ligula. Morbi enim ligula, euismod eu ornare id, pharetra et sapien.
        Sed aliquam, elit vitae aliquet iaculis, leo sapien rutrum ipsum, at fermentum nibh dolor ac risus.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc a orci auctor, ornare leo at, convallis neque. Mauris congue, massa ac faucibus aliquam, diam dui porta
        purus, sed consequat
        eros dolor ac ex. Vivamus augue orci, bibendum nec imperdiet sit amet, fringilla at lacus. Nullam condimentum
        dolor eu dolor consequat, a ullamcorper eros congue. Aliquam varius nec elit et posuere. In rutrum et mi
        a tristique. Praesent at magna a magna vestibulum vulputate. Ut vulputate, leo nec blandit fermentum, urna
        dolor efficitur erat, vitae aliquam risus diam eget libero.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus vel augue quis felis lacinia fermentum. Donec laoreet mauris non orci tincidunt maximus. Curabitur
        mattis tincidunt
        eros, et pellentesque eros venenatis ut. Mauris eget justo nec leo maximus interdum. Vestibulum aliquet lorem
        commodo, semper enim bibendum, pretium nisi. Donec ultricies, nibh vitae dapibus porttitor, lorem nulla bibendum
        justo, et posuere orci tellus in nisl. Aenean volutpat dui et porttitor varius. Duis a magna luctus, porta
        sem at, consectetur nisl. Curabitur in venenatis sem, id tempus quam. Aenean ut lorem ipsum. Donec eget ligula
        fermentum, viverra nunc ut, vehicula lorem. Aenean maximus varius sodales. Aliquam sed ipsum nec diam pharetra
        vehicula.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vivamus dignissim pretium mi, in dictum nunc iaculis quis. Nullam auctor aliquet eros, bibendum rutrum libero
        aliquam vitae.
        Nullam congue dolor at diam fermentum pretium. Duis a lectus in sem hendrerit ullamcorper eget tempus orci.
        Pellentesque ac nulla eu risus tempus scelerisque. Phasellus et vestibulum eros, ac convallis elit. Duis
        convallis feugiat justo, at aliquet quam pretium volutpat. Ut sit amet vulputate justo, eget ultricies neque.
        Mauris aliquam arcu ut lorem laoreet luctus. Sed eget ligula rutrum, tincidunt augue vel, fermentum turpis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ut vehicula quam orci, vel commodo mauris gravida nec. Quisque pharetra commodo dolor bibendum pulvinar. Nunc id
        quam ac
        ante placerat dapibus. Aenean erat leo, laoreet et nibh at, egestas aliquet sapien. Sed pharetra orci eget
        est semper fermentum. Fusce leo erat, finibus sed pulvinar eget, eleifend quis lectus. Cras volutpat sodales
        arcu, a consectetur mauris laoreet in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu commodo orci, sed elementum massa. Nam sit amet
        elementum
        ipsum, eu laoreet metus. Aenean a ex vel erat aliquam imperdiet eu at justo. Nulla in lobortis tellus. Curabitur
        varius laoreet quam non facilisis. Etiam consequat purus elit, vel euismod ligula faucibus fringilla. Etiam
        cursus dui eros, non egestas nibh congue a. Nullam eu justo neque. Cras rutrum arcu elit. Quisque vestibulum
        et mi vel congue. Curabitur a ultrices ligula. Morbi enim ligula, euismod eu ornare id, pharetra et sapien.
        Sed aliquam, elit vitae aliquet iaculis, leo sapien rutrum ipsum, at fermentum nibh dolor ac risus.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc a orci auctor, ornare leo at, convallis neque. Mauris congue, massa ac faucibus aliquam, diam dui porta
        purus, sed consequat
        eros dolor ac ex. Vivamus augue orci, bibendum nec imperdiet sit amet, fringilla at lacus. Nullam condimentum
        dolor eu dolor consequat, a ullamcorper eros congue. Aliquam varius nec elit et posuere. In rutrum et mi
        a tristique. Praesent at magna a magna vestibulum vulputate. Ut vulputate, leo nec blandit fermentum, urna
        dolor efficitur erat, vitae aliquam risus diam eget libero.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus vel augue quis felis lacinia fermentum. Donec laoreet mauris non orci tincidunt maximus. Curabitur
        mattis tincidunt
        eros, et pellentesque eros venenatis ut. Mauris eget justo nec leo maximus interdum. Vestibulum aliquet lorem
        commodo, semper enim bibendum, pretium nisi. Donec ultricies, nibh vitae dapibus porttitor, lorem nulla bibendum
        justo, et posuere orci tellus in nisl. Aenean volutpat dui et porttitor varius. Duis a magna luctus, porta
        sem at, consectetur nisl. Curabitur in venenatis sem, id tempus quam. Aenean ut lorem ipsum. Donec eget ligula
        fermentum, viverra nunc ut, vehicula lorem. Aenean maximus varius sodales. Aliquam sed ipsum nec diam pharetra
        vehicula.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vivamus dignissim pretium mi, in dictum nunc iaculis quis. Nullam auctor aliquet eros, bibendum rutrum libero
        aliquam vitae.
        Nullam congue dolor at diam fermentum pretium. Duis a lectus in sem hendrerit ullamcorper eget tempus orci.
        Pellentesque ac nulla eu risus tempus scelerisque. Phasellus et vestibulum eros, ac convallis elit. Duis
        convallis feugiat justo, at aliquet quam pretium volutpat. Ut sit amet vulputate justo, eget ultricies neque.
        Mauris aliquam arcu ut lorem laoreet luctus. Sed eget ligula rutrum, tincidunt augue vel, fermentum turpis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ut vehicula quam orci, vel commodo mauris gravida nec. Quisque pharetra commodo dolor bibendum pulvinar. Nunc id
        quam ac
        ante placerat dapibus. Aenean erat leo, laoreet et nibh at, egestas aliquet sapien. Sed pharetra orci eget
        est semper fermentum. Fusce leo erat, finibus sed pulvinar eget, eleifend quis lectus. Cras volutpat sodales
        arcu, a consectetur mauris laoreet in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu commodo orci, sed elementum massa. Nam sit amet
        elementum
        ipsum, eu laoreet metus. Aenean a ex vel erat aliquam imperdiet eu at justo. Nulla in lobortis tellus. Curabitur
        varius laoreet quam non facilisis. Etiam consequat purus elit, vel euismod ligula faucibus fringilla. Etiam
        cursus dui eros, non egestas nibh congue a. Nullam eu justo neque. Cras rutrum arcu elit. Quisque vestibulum
        et mi vel congue. Curabitur a ultrices ligula. Morbi enim ligula, euismod eu ornare id, pharetra et sapien.
        Sed aliquam, elit vitae aliquet iaculis, leo sapien rutrum ipsum, at fermentum nibh dolor ac risus.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc a orci auctor, ornare leo at, convallis neque. Mauris congue, massa ac faucibus aliquam, diam dui porta
        purus, sed consequat
        eros dolor ac ex. Vivamus augue orci, bibendum nec imperdiet sit amet, fringilla at lacus. Nullam condimentum
        dolor eu dolor consequat, a ullamcorper eros congue. Aliquam varius nec elit et posuere. In rutrum et mi
        a tristique. Praesent at magna a magna vestibulum vulputate. Ut vulputate, leo nec blandit fermentum, urna
        dolor efficitur erat, vitae aliquam risus diam eget libero.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus vel augue quis felis lacinia fermentum. Donec laoreet mauris non orci tincidunt maximus. Curabitur
        mattis tincidunt
        eros, et pellentesque eros venenatis ut. Mauris eget justo nec leo maximus interdum. Vestibulum aliquet lorem
        commodo, semper enim bibendum, pretium nisi. Donec ultricies, nibh vitae dapibus porttitor, lorem nulla bibendum
        justo, et posuere orci tellus in nisl. Aenean volutpat dui et porttitor varius. Duis a magna luctus, porta
        sem at, consectetur nisl. Curabitur in venenatis sem, id tempus quam. Aenean ut lorem ipsum. Donec eget ligula
        fermentum, viverra nunc ut, vehicula lorem. Aenean maximus varius sodales. Aliquam sed ipsum nec diam pharetra
        vehicula.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vivamus dignissim pretium mi, in dictum nunc iaculis quis. Nullam auctor aliquet eros, bibendum rutrum libero
        aliquam vitae.
        Nullam congue dolor at diam fermentum pretium. Duis a lectus in sem hendrerit ullamcorper eget tempus orci.
        Pellentesque ac nulla eu risus tempus scelerisque. Phasellus et vestibulum eros, ac convallis elit. Duis
        convallis feugiat justo, at aliquet quam pretium volutpat. Ut sit amet vulputate justo, eget ultricies neque.
        Mauris aliquam arcu ut lorem laoreet luctus. Sed eget ligula rutrum, tincidunt augue vel, fermentum turpis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ut vehicula quam orci, vel commodo mauris gravida nec. Quisque pharetra commodo dolor bibendum pulvinar. Nunc id
        quam ac
        ante placerat dapibus. Aenean erat leo, laoreet et nibh at, egestas aliquet sapien. Sed pharetra orci eget
        est semper fermentum. Fusce leo erat, finibus sed pulvinar eget, eleifend quis lectus. Cras volutpat sodales
        arcu, a consectetur mauris laoreet in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu commodo orci, sed elementum massa. Nam sit amet
        elementum
        ipsum, eu laoreet metus. Aenean a ex vel erat aliquam imperdiet eu at justo. Nulla in lobortis tellus. Curabitur
        varius laoreet quam non facilisis. Etiam consequat purus elit, vel euismod ligula faucibus fringilla. Etiam
        cursus dui eros, non egestas nibh congue a. Nullam eu justo neque. Cras rutrum arcu elit. Quisque vestibulum
        et mi vel congue. Curabitur a ultrices ligula. Morbi enim ligula, euismod eu ornare id, pharetra et sapien.
        Sed aliquam, elit vitae aliquet iaculis, leo sapien rutrum ipsum, at fermentum nibh dolor ac risus.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc a orci auctor, ornare leo at, convallis neque. Mauris congue, massa ac faucibus aliquam, diam dui porta
        purus, sed consequat
        eros dolor ac ex. Vivamus augue orci, bibendum nec imperdiet sit amet, fringilla at lacus. Nullam condimentum
        dolor eu dolor consequat, a ullamcorper eros congue. Aliquam varius nec elit et posuere. In rutrum et mi
        a tristique. Praesent at magna a magna vestibulum vulputate. Ut vulputate, leo nec blandit fermentum, urna
        dolor efficitur erat, vitae aliquam risus diam eget libero.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus vel augue quis felis lacinia fermentum. Donec laoreet mauris non orci tincidunt maximus. Curabitur
        mattis tincidunt
        eros, et pellentesque eros venenatis ut. Mauris eget justo nec leo maximus interdum. Vestibulum aliquet lorem
        commodo, semper enim bibendum, pretium nisi. Donec ultricies, nibh vitae dapibus porttitor, lorem nulla bibendum
        justo, et posuere orci tellus in nisl. Aenean volutpat dui et porttitor varius. Duis a magna luctus, porta
        sem at, consectetur nisl. Curabitur in venenatis sem, id tempus quam. Aenean ut lorem ipsum. Donec eget ligula
        fermentum, viverra nunc ut, vehicula lorem. Aenean maximus varius sodales. Aliquam sed ipsum nec diam pharetra
        vehicula.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vivamus dignissim pretium mi, in dictum nunc iaculis quis. Nullam auctor aliquet eros, bibendum rutrum libero
        aliquam vitae.
        Nullam congue dolor at diam fermentum pretium. Duis a lectus in sem hendrerit ullamcorper eget tempus orci.
        Pellentesque ac nulla eu risus tempus scelerisque. Phasellus et vestibulum eros, ac convallis elit. Duis
        convallis feugiat justo, at aliquet quam pretium volutpat. Ut sit amet vulputate justo, eget ultricies neque.
        Mauris aliquam arcu ut lorem laoreet luctus. Sed eget ligula rutrum, tincidunt augue vel, fermentum turpis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ut vehicula quam orci, vel commodo mauris gravida nec. Quisque pharetra commodo dolor bibendum pulvinar. Nunc id
        quam ac
        ante placerat dapibus. Aenean erat leo, laoreet et nibh at, egestas aliquet sapien. Sed pharetra orci eget
        est semper fermentum. Fusce leo erat, finibus sed pulvinar eget, eleifend quis lectus. Cras volutpat sodales
        arcu, a consectetur mauris laoreet in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu commodo orci, sed elementum massa. Nam sit amet
        elementum
        ipsum, eu laoreet metus. Aenean a ex vel erat aliquam imperdiet eu at justo. Nulla in lobortis tellus. Curabitur
        varius laoreet quam non facilisis. Etiam consequat purus elit, vel euismod ligula faucibus fringilla. Etiam
        cursus dui eros, non egestas nibh congue a. Nullam eu justo neque. Cras rutrum arcu elit. Quisque vestibulum
        et mi vel congue. Curabitur a ultrices ligula. Morbi enim ligula, euismod eu ornare id, pharetra et sapien.
        Sed aliquam, elit vitae aliquet iaculis, leo sapien rutrum ipsum, at fermentum nibh dolor ac risus.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc a orci auctor, ornare leo at, convallis neque. Mauris congue, massa ac faucibus aliquam, diam dui porta
        purus, sed consequat
        eros dolor ac ex. Vivamus augue orci, bibendum nec imperdiet sit amet, fringilla at lacus. Nullam condimentum
        dolor eu dolor consequat, a ullamcorper eros congue. Aliquam varius nec elit et posuere. In rutrum et mi
        a tristique. Praesent at magna a magna vestibulum vulputate. Ut vulputate, leo nec blandit fermentum, urna
        dolor efficitur erat, vitae aliquam risus diam eget libero.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus vel augue quis felis lacinia fermentum. Donec laoreet mauris non orci tincidunt maximus. Curabitur
        mattis tincidunt
        eros, et pellentesque eros venenatis ut. Mauris eget justo nec leo maximus interdum. Vestibulum aliquet lorem
        commodo, semper enim bibendum, pretium nisi. Donec ultricies, nibh vitae dapibus porttitor, lorem nulla bibendum
        justo, et posuere orci tellus in nisl. Aenean volutpat dui et porttitor varius. Duis a magna luctus, porta
        sem at, consectetur nisl. Curabitur in venenatis sem, id tempus quam. Aenean ut lorem ipsum. Donec eget ligula
        fermentum, viverra nunc ut, vehicula lorem. Aenean maximus varius sodales. Aliquam sed ipsum nec diam pharetra
        vehicula.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vivamus dignissim pretium mi, in dictum nunc iaculis quis. Nullam auctor aliquet eros, bibendum rutrum libero
        aliquam vitae.
        Nullam congue dolor at diam fermentum pretium. Duis a lectus in sem hendrerit ullamcorper eget tempus orci.
        Pellentesque ac nulla eu risus tempus scelerisque. Phasellus et vestibulum eros, ac convallis elit. Duis
        convallis feugiat justo, at aliquet quam pretium volutpat. Ut sit amet vulputate justo, eget ultricies neque.
        Mauris aliquam arcu ut lorem laoreet luctus. Sed eget ligula rutrum, tincidunt augue vel, fermentum turpis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ut vehicula quam orci, vel commodo mauris gravida nec. Quisque pharetra commodo dolor bibendum pulvinar. Nunc id
        quam ac
        ante placerat dapibus. Aenean erat leo, laoreet et nibh at, egestas aliquet sapien. Sed pharetra orci eget
        est semper fermentum. Fusce leo erat, finibus sed pulvinar eget, eleifend quis lectus. Cras volutpat sodales
        arcu, a consectetur mauris laoreet in.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu commodo orci, sed elementum massa. Nam sit amet
        elementum
        ipsum, eu laoreet metus. Aenean a ex vel erat aliquam imperdiet eu at justo. Nulla in lobortis tellus. Curabitur
        varius laoreet quam non facilisis. Etiam consequat purus elit, vel euismod ligula faucibus fringilla. Etiam
        cursus dui eros, non egestas nibh congue a. Nullam eu justo neque. Cras rutrum arcu elit. Quisque vestibulum
        et mi vel congue. Curabitur a ultrices ligula. Morbi enim ligula, euismod eu ornare id, pharetra et sapien.
        Sed aliquam, elit vitae aliquet iaculis, leo sapien rutrum ipsum, at fermentum nibh dolor ac risus.
      </p>
      <p>
        Nunc a orci auctor, ornare leo at, convallis neque. Mauris congue, massa ac faucibus aliquam, diam dui porta
        purus, sed consequat
        eros dolor ac ex. Vivamus augue orci, bibendum nec imperdiet sit amet, fringilla at lacus. Nullam condimentum
        dolor eu dolor consequat, a ullamcorper eros congue. Aliquam varius nec elit et posuere. In rutrum et mi
        a tristique. Praesent at magna a magna vestibulum vulputate. Ut vulputate, leo nec blandit fermentum, urna
        dolor efficitur erat, vitae aliquam risus diam eget libero.
      </p>
      <p>
        Phasellus vel augue quis felis lacinia fermentum. Donec laoreet mauris non orci tincidunt maximus. Curabitur
        mattis tincidunt
        eros, et pellentesque eros venenatis ut. Mauris eget justo nec leo maximus interdum. Vestibulum aliquet lorem
        commodo, semper enim bibendum, pretium nisi. Donec ultricies, nibh vitae dapibus porttitor, lorem nulla bibendum
        justo, et posuere orci tellus in nisl. Aenean volutpat dui et porttitor varius. Duis a magna luctus, porta
        sem at, consectetur nisl. Curabitur in venenatis sem, id tempus quam. Aenean ut lorem ipsum. Donec eget ligula
        fermentum, viverra nunc ut, vehicula lorem. Aenean maximus varius sodales. Aliquam sed ipsum nec diam pharetra
        vehicula.
      </p>
      <p>
        Vivamus dignissim pretium mi, in dictum nunc iaculis quis. Nullam auctor aliquet eros, bibendum rutrum libero
        aliquam vitae.
        Nullam congue dolor at diam fermentum pretium. Duis a lectus in sem hendrerit ullamcorper eget tempus orci.
        Pellentesque ac nulla eu risus tempus scelerisque. Phasellus et vestibulum eros, ac convallis elit. Duis
        convallis feugiat justo, at aliquet quam pretium volutpat. Ut sit amet vulputate justo, eget ultricies neque.
        Mauris aliquam arcu ut lorem laoreet luctus. Sed eget ligula rutrum, tincidunt augue vel, fermentum turpis.
      </p>
      <p>
        Ut vehicula quam orci, vel commodo mauris gravida nec. Quisque pharetra commodo dolor bibendum pulvinar. Nunc id
        quam ac
        ante placerat dapibus. Aenean erat leo, laoreet et nibh at, egestas aliquet sapien. Sed pharetra orci eget
        est semper fermentum. Fusce leo erat, finibus sed pulvinar eget, eleifend quis lectus. Cras volutpat sodales
        arcu, a consectetur mauris laoreet in.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much already. Here's the working code from what I've done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/nj73t10v/

Comment: I've tried your code as well which is working!! nevertheless I'd like the full bar visible in grey (like in my code), and then the green which is the progress already made. Do you think that's possible? or if that's too complicated, maybe the percentage shown next to the bar of your code? I'll create a working code of what yours looks like

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dgkbwurs/ somehow it only works when the width of div.lerneinheit is at 70%, when I put in less the bar disappears

Comment: Ok, I prepared a version with gray and green progress. A setting where this progress is already yours. https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/6vwfou4a/1/